# Why is Exception not raised immediately in anonymous PL/SQL block?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, exception

In the following code, when the input to the principle amount is less than zero or negative it should raise the exception and exit. But the following executes all the statements in the block and at the end displays the error message written in the exception block.

I want Oracle to make an exit once the exception is raised. Kindly help with me to fix this.

```
declare
    principle1 number;
    rate1 number;
    r1 number;
    years1 number;
    interest1 number;
    principle2 number;
    rate2 number;
    r2 number;
    years2 number;
    interest2 number;
    invalid_entry exception;
begin

    principle1 := &principle1_amount1;

    if (principle1 <= 0) then
      raise invalid_entry;
    end if;

    rate1 := &rate_interest1;
    r1 := rate1/100;
    years1 := &years1;
    interest1 := ComptInt_jk(principle1,r1,years1);

    dbms_output.put_line('The interest for the principle amount ' || principle1
                         || ' for ' || years1 || ' year/s at the rate of ' || rate1
                         ||'% is '||interest1);

    principle2 := &principle1_amount2;
    rate2 := &rate_interest1;
    r2 := rate2/100;
    years2 := &years2;
    interest2 := ComptInt_jk(principle2,r2,years2);

    dbms_output.put_line('The interest for the principle amount ' || principle2
                         || ' for ' || years2 || ' year/s at the rate of ' || rate2
                         ||'% is '||interest2);
exception
    when invalid_entry then
       dbms_output.put_line('The data entered cannot be zero or negative ');
end;
/
```

Comment: First, I don't understand the question.  What is the code that you posted doing or not doing that you want to change?  What do you want the code to do instead?  Second, you've posted two questions both of which have subjects that start with "#Oracle#PL/SQL:".  That's not a term that anyone else is likely to search on so I'm not sure why you're doing that.  My bias is to fix both subjects but I figured I'd ask because you're apparently doing that intentionally.

Comment: I was about to mention the hashtags (?) in the titles too; that's what the tags are for. Are you saying you get all the `dbms_output` messages; or just that you're prompted for all the substitution variables? If the latter then as with your previous question you are not understanding how the block is parsed and are trying to get PL/SQL to do something it isn't designed for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "When the input to the principle amount is less than zero or -ve it
>   should raise the exception and exit but the following executes all the
>   statements in the block and at the end displays the error message
>   written in the exception block"

Hmm, not quite.  What happens is that SQL*Plus requires us to enter values for *all* the input parameters.  Your code expects five input parameters so it presents five prompts.

Once we've entered all the requirement parameters the program evaluates `if (principle1<=0 ) then` and if it's negative then it raise the exception. Control flow then moves to the Exception block.

None of the other messages are displayed.  So the actual code is not executed.  Check it out:

```
.... 
 38* end;
Enter value for principle1_amount1: -89
old  16:     principle1:=&principle1_amount1;
new  16:     principle1:=-89;
Enter value for rate_interest1: 12
old  20:     rate1:=&rate_interest1;
new  20:     rate1:=12;
Enter value for years1: 12
old  22:     years1:=&years1;
new  22:     years1:=12;
Enter value for principle1_amount2: 12
old  25:     principle2:=&principle1_amount2;
new  25:     principle2:=12;
Enter value for rate_interest1: 12
old  26:     rate2:=&rate_interest1;
new  26:     rate2:=12;
Enter value for years2: 12
old  28:     years2:=&years2;
new  28:     years2:=12;
The data entered cannot be zero or negative

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```